# Como filtrar datos en Chart JS asp.net y sql server?

Tags: javascript, sql-server, ajax, asp.net-mvc, chart.js

estoy intentando filtrar datos y que estos cambios se vean reflejados en un grafico que tengo....todo esta hecho con asp.net y sql server usando ChartJS

Me conecto a un procedimiento almacenado

```
 public List<Barra3> RetornarGraficos1()
 {
     List<Barra3> objLista = new List<Barra3>();

     //Data Source=;Initial Catalog= ; User ID= ; Password=
     using (SqlConnection oconexion = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.; Initial Catalog=LID_RIESG_COMERC; Integrated Security=True"))
     {
         string query = "ProductividadM";

         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, oconexion);
         cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

         oconexion.Open();

         using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
         {
             while (dr.Read())
             {
                 objLista.Add(new Barra3()
                 {
                     Fecha = dr["Fecha"].ToString(),
                     Centro = decimal.Parse(dr["Centro"].ToString()),
                     Occidente = decimal.Parse(dr["Occidente"].ToString()),
                     Oriente = decimal.Parse(dr["Oriente"].ToString()),
                 });
             }
         }
     }

     return objLista;
 }
```

mi clase

```
public class Barra3
{
    public string Fecha { get; set; }
    public decimal Centro { get; set; }
    public decimal Occidente { get; set; }
    public decimal Oriente { get; set; }
}
```

el Controlador

```
 [HttpGet]
 public JsonResult ReporteGraficos1()
 {
     DT_Reporte objDT_Reporte = new DT_Reporte();

     List<Barra3> objLista = objDT_Reporte.RetornarGraficos1();

     return Json(objLista, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

mi vista

```
    <div class="col-lg-9">
        <div class="panel panel-default">



            <select id="cars">
                <option value="01/06/23">01/06/23</option>
                <option value="15/07/23">15/07/23</option>
                <option value="12/08/23">12/08/23</option>
                <option value="23/09/23" selected>23/09/23</option>
            </select>


            <div class="panel-heading"><b>Operaciones Aprobadas</b> </div>
            <div class="panel-body">


                <div class="wrapper">
                    <canvas id="myChart2"></canvas>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

el JS

```
<script>
       jQuery.ajax({
             url: '@Url.Action("ReporteGraficos1", "Home")',
             type: "GET",
             dataType: "json",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             success: function (data) {

                 /*console.log(data);*/

                 var arrayMeses = [];
                 var arrayCentro = [];
                 var arrayOccidente = [];
                 var arrayOriente = [];

                 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                     /*console.log(data[i].mes)*/
                    arrayMeses.push(data[i].Fecha)
                     arrayCentro.push(data[i].Centro)
                     arrayOccidente.push(data[i].Occidente)
                     arrayOriente.push(data[i].Oriente)
                 }

                 console.log(arrayMeses)
                 console.log(arrayCentro)
                 console.log(arrayOccidente)
                 console.log(arrayOriente)



     var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart2").getContext('2d');
     var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
         type: 'bar',
         data: {
             labels: arrayMeses,
             datasets: [{
                 label: 'Centro',
                 backgroundColor: "#0E5185",
                 data: arrayCentro,
             }, {
                 label: 'Occidente',
                 backgroundColor: "#EE8A31",
                 data: arrayOccidente,
             }, {
                 label: 'Oriente',
                 backgroundColor: "#BFC6C5",
                 data:  arrayOriente,
             }],
         },
         options: {
             tooltips: {
                 displayColors: true,
                 //callbacks: {
                 //    mode: 'x',
                 //},
             },
             scales: {
                 xAxes: [{
                     stacked: true,
                     gridLines: {
                         display: false,
                     }
                 }],
                 yAxes: [{
                     stacked: true,
                     ticks: {
                         beginAtZero: true,
                     },
                     type: 'linear',
                 }]
             },
             responsive: true,
             maintainAspectRatio: true,
             legend: { position: 'bottom' },
         }
     });

        },
           error: function (error) {
               console.log(error)
           }

    });

 </script>
```

y el resultado, lo que intento es cargar los datos de los meses del SP, en el option value y que esto me filtre y se refleje en los graficos.

Tambien he estado pensando poder añadir dos option value y poder filtrar entre dos fechas, solo que no se como podria hacerlos, eh intentado buscar informacion pero no he logrado comprenderla

[image: Tambien he estado poder añadir dos option value y poder filtrar entre dos fechas, solo que no se como podria hacerlos, eh intentado buscar informacion pero no he logrado comprenderla]